# pdo_error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in agile toolkit

Tags: atk4

I have uploaded my codes to host and now it throw exception: (it works perfectly in local)

```
Error in AJAX response: SyntaxError: syntax error
Application Error: Database Query Failed

Exception_DB, code: 0

Additional information:

    pdo_error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[options] [field] [from] [table] [join] [where] [group] [having] [order] [limit]' at line 1
    mode: select
    params:
    query: select [options] [field] [from] [table] [join] [where] [group] [having] [order] [limit]
    template: select [options] [field] [from] [table] [join] [where] [group] [having] [order] [limit]

/home/test/public_html/temp/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php:1513
```

Comment: This is not a question, however by the looks of it it seems that you used an incorrect syntax for your SQL query. Here is the documentation if you need the correct syntax: https://mariadb.org/docs/

Comment: I think this is from agile toolkit! there should be some conflicts between Mysql and Mariadb for agile tookit...

Comment: Have you changed config settings on host (uploaded db dump)? Do you use the same version of ATK?

ATK works only with MySQL and Mongo for now

Comment: Yes @stakantin. I tested it on a host with MySQL and it worked truely but on this host (with MariaDB) it has these errors... MariaDB is compatible with MySQL so where is the problem?

Comment: try do add debug query here